# Optimize list loading in nuxt.js

Tags: pagination, nuxt.js

I have list of products in my ecommerce project, instead of clicking on fetch next N records, I wanted to load it when user scroll to end of the page, how to do that ?

As of now I am doing pagination with button click and using pagination component

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Intersection Observer API concept to achieve this. This will allow you to load the data when the user is about to enter into that view.
I have created a small article [Nuxt.js List optimization](https://medium.com/@manish.tict2009/optimizing-list-load-in-nuxt-js-with-intersection-observer-279442fa45c7) related to list optimization. Please read this and try to implement in your project.

Comment: Please see [How to not be a spammer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion).